# Jquery: How to i find and elements like this <p>MyHeader</p>

Tags: jquery, html

Using Jquery, how do I find and hide elements like this?

```
<p>MyHeader</p>
```

The only identifier is MyHeader here, so trying to find elements that exactly match this and hide them.

Edit:
I don't have a choice to add ids or class selectors, that would have made life easier :-)
anyway, I found jquery contains seems to be of help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('p:contains(MyHeader)').hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to add a class to the p tag.

So you would do something like this:

```
 <p class="myClass">MyHeader</p>
```

Then you can hide that using the following jQuery

```
 $(".myClass").hide()
```

Comment: It wasnt me that downvoted but i think it is because the OP specifically said he couldn't add id's or class's

Answer (score 1):

Jquery API has a Contain function:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/content-filter-selector/

This is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>John Resig</div>

<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>


<script>
$("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p:contains('MyHeader')").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id or class definition to the p tag

HTML

```
<p class="header">MyHeader</p>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.header').hide();
```